# How to use GlobeAPI to Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0, packagist

Right now, I am studying migration from 2.x to Version 3 of CakePHP.
I have developed a simple sending of sms using GlobeLabs API (one of available SMS Gateway in the Philippines).
https://github.com/globelabs/api

Right now, I know what's the essence of composer and unfortunately, there are no hosted or uploaded package of Globelabs API in the packagist and I believe that App::import("Vendor","filepath") are now deprecated and not supported in the new version.

How can I utilize GlobeAPI in CakePHP 3?
I will appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the lib somewhere and define a path for the autoloader in your apps composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Your\\Lib\\": "./some/path/to/your/lib/src"
    }
},
```

It will tell composer to look in that folder when loading something from your libs namespace.

Comment: An run `composer dumpautoload` after that

Comment: should I put this autoload in the composer.json found in the root file of cakephp 3?

Comment: The root folder of your cake3 application. If you don't know how to work with composer I highly recommend you to become familiar with it. Composer is a *very* common tool for php development these days. Almost every project provides composer support.

Comment: Yep. Actually, I am new in composer and I've already know what's the essence of it in the production. I have already utilized the GlobeAPI by including and declaring the exact path of the said API in the autoload_classmap.php under the composer folder in the vendor folder of cakephp 3. I've already tested of calling the class of GlobeAPI in the view, however what I want to do is to call the class of GlobeAPI to the controller. Is there a way to call the class of the said API to the controller? Thanks